# trigger OnExceptionAspect from MethodInterceptionAspect

Tags: c#, exception, interceptor, postsharp

I want to get to `MyExceptionAspect.OnException` when an exception is thrown from `MyInterceptorAspect.OnInvoke` so the following code will return "Much love":

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        [MyInterceptorAspect]
        [MyExceptionAspect]
        public string Do()
        {
            return "LOVE";
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class MyInterceptorAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
    {
        public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            // ...
            throw new Exception("Much love");
            // ...
            // base.OnInvoke(args) is NOT called.
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class MyExceptionAspect : OnExceptionAspect
    {
        public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            args.ReturnValue = args.Exception.Message;
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
        }
    }
```

At runtime, when the exception is thrown from the interceptor, it's not caught by `OnExceptionAspect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out while writing the question :)

In compile-time, PostSharp uses `OnExceptionAspect` to wrap the `Do` method with try-catch, and insert a call for `MethodInterceptionAspect.OnInvoke` on the first line of it - so the order of the aspects matter to the fact if that call will be included in the `try` block.

So this change solved it nicely:

```
    public class MyClass
    {

        [MyExceptionAspect(AspectPriority = 1)]
        [MyInterceptorAspect(AspectPriority = 2)]
        public string Do()
        {
            return "LOVE";
        }
    }
```